# Removing newlines from the end of base.html file makes some elements disappear from DOM

Tags: django, django-templates

This is a strange bug. I have an html file that extends a base template called *base.html*. I noticed that a `script` tag right before the end `body` tag in the base template doesn't show up in the DOM in the Elements tab of the Chrome dev tools, and the tag is cut off completely along with the rest of the html file in the Sources tab. This happens in Chrome, Mozilla, and Safari, so it must be a problem on the Django side. And obviously the observable effects on the page that the script should create aren't happening either.

Here's the end of the rendered html in the Sources tab:

```
  <section>
    what is going on
  </section>
<footer></footer>
<script src="/static/home/js/ba
```

Completely cut off. Here's the end of that base template:

```
  {% block main %}{% endblock %}

  <footer></footer>

  <script src="{% static 'home/js/base.js' %}"></script>
  {% block js %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Now, here's where it gets funny. The trouble is at the end of the file, so I just added some newlines to see if there's any difference in the DOM is rendered:

```
  {% block main %}{% endblock %}

  <footer></footer>

  <script src="{% static 'home/js/base.js' %}"></script>
  {% block js %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And the Sources tab showed a cut off later in the tag:

```
  <section>
    what is going on
  </section>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="/static/home/js/base.j
```

I won't paste it here, but I added about 35 newlines to the end of the file before I got what I wanted in the Sources. It seems that every newline cuts off the rendered html one character later.

```
  <section>
    what is going on
  </section>
<footer></footer>
<script src="/static/home/js/base.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the effects from the script finally worked. This feels like a temporary solution to something deeper that needs to be fixed. Anybody have any clue what the hell is going on or where to look?

**Edit:** Here's the template (located in the *work* app) that extends *base.html* (located in the *home* app), called *work.html*:

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}

{% block css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'work/css/work.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
  <section>
    hello
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the view that renders it:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def work(request):
    return render(request, 'work/work.html', {})
```

**Edit 2:** some more unexpected results:

When I deleted the script (so that I can paste it in head as suggested in the comments), the end of the rendered html was this:

```
<section> what is going on </section>
```

And pasting right before the `</head>` tag resulted in:

```
<section> what is going on </section> 
<
```

Same result above when I commented it out in head.

Commenting out the script when it's before the `</body>` results in this:

```
<section> what is going on </section> 
<footer></footer> 
<!-- <script src="/static/home/js/base.j
```

And replacing single quotes with double quotes resulted in the rendered html showing double quotes instead of single quotes as the only difference. :/

Then I deleted almost everything so that my code was this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>
```

And that rendered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<scrip
```

I added back some tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:357
```

For some reason, the script tag generated by django-livereload-server remains. This is what the full script tag looks like: 
`<script src="http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js"></script></head>`

Comment: That's curious :) Can you show us what you use to render this template?

Comment: @bug Yes, so the base template is in the _home_ app, and _work.html_ is the template that extends the base template and is located in the _work_ app. I added the _views.py_ that renders _work.html_ and the template itself in the edit above.

Comment: This is strange! Is this happening to the last script tag only? What will happen if the script tag is in <head> ? try the script tag rendering inside html comment also: <!-- <script.... -->    Can you show , what are the results ?

Comment: use double quotes like <script src="{% static "home/js/base.js" %}"></script>. and have you added the {% load static %} in the base file

Comment: @w4113 I did the things you asked and posted the results in my Edit 2. Then I began to go on a deleting spree and found that the django-livereload-server was the culprit. See the end of the Edit 2 and my answer below. Spent a whole day on this, phewwww.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery's over everybody. The problem is that you should not `pip install django-livereload-server`. I don't know what it does behind the scenes but some of my html disappear based on some weird algorithm.

So, to uninstall django-livereload-server, remove `'livereload',` from your `INSTALLED_APPS`, remove `'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',` from your `MIDDLEWARE`, hit Control-C to get out of that livereload terminal process, Control-C in the window running the `runserver` process to apply the changes (because livereload latches onto runserver like a leech, so you have to restart), and enjoy expected output. And `pip uninstall django-livereload-server`. If anybody has any suggestions for a livereload type of app that works (where the browser reloads the page when you type something new in your html/js/css), let me know. For now I guess it's back to the old manually typed Command-R.